# I'm trying to set up a view with a background image and a slider

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I also want to be able to change the image programmatically so that I can attach a listener and change the image at specific points. I'm at the early stages of this and I'm having trouble setting up the view I have;

```
//inside my activity

LinearLayout mLayout;

//then inside the oncreate

mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main1);
setContentView(mLayout);
mLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic);
```

This compiles fine in eclipse but when I run it the app fails to start.

I'm looking to create a slide show with music.

I have tried the solutions given below but I am still getting an error;

12-06 11:51:11.656: E/AndroidRuntime(238): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

Ultimately I want a slide show that will allow me to set the background image programmatically so I'm trying to get a handle on a view so that I can set the background through a listener.

I have set up a view
res/layout/slider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seek"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:secondaryProgress="75" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tracking"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

SeekBar mSeekBar;
TextView mProgressText;
TextView mTrackingText;
LinearLayout mLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek);
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    mProgressText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progress);
    mTrackingText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tracking);


    setContentView(R.layout.slider);
    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main2);
    setContentView(mLayout);
    mLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mumbai);

    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
            mProgressText.setText(progress + " " +
                    getString(R.string.seekbar_from_touch) + "=" + fromTouch);
            //mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main1);
            //mLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boats);
    }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mTrackingText.setText(getString(R.string.seekbar_tracking_on));
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mTrackingText.setText(getString(R.string.seekbar_tracking_off));
        }
}
```

Hi Pratick as I wrote below I'm still getting an error.

12-06 13:02:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(808): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

Although I don't think it is very informative. This was after I commented out the second call to setContentView(mLayout).

I've just ran it through the debugger and its erred at
     mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

I had no success with the suggestions and have tried a new tactic
I'm now trying to use a LayoutInflater but I'm getting the same error on the AVD and when I step through the code Just as I think I'm about to leave the line that calls 'inflater.inflate' it gives the error "source not found" and brings up a window in the debugger code pane that allows me to navigate.
I've created the 2 views in xml and received no errros when I saved

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PwdDialogActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.password_dialog,
                (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root));
        //layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boats);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(layout);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this error and the previous error has nothing to do with the code and is more concerned with my set up. But I have created the project and AVD to run in version 3. I've looked up LayoutInflater and it says it's been about since version 1.

Comment: Hi yes - 12-06 13:02:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(808): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception - I don't think its very informative though. This error was given when I commented out the second call to setContentView(mLayout) as suggested by @Pratik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without setting any layout in `setContentView()` and find the object by it's ID it's always getting null.

You need to first set the layout and then get object id from that layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout); // here set the layout where object or control where defined it
mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main1);
setContentView(mLayout); // and then you can set that object
```

Comment: Thanks Pratik and @JSydow I have tried to get this to work but I don't think I have my views set up correctly. I have the main view set up with the id main1 this has the seekbar controller on it but I don't think this is correct.

Comment: I have  created a new view called main and this is unedited. I have renamed main1 to res/layout/slider.xml with the id main2. My code is now 
        
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
            mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main2);
            setContentView(mLayout);
        
        sorry about the multiple updates, I'm having trouble putting code in without using the return

Comment: just remove the last setContentView() or put in comment. I think you just want to change the background for current layout then no need to use this method even if you set background on main LinearLayout of your layout file

Comment: Hi Pratik that is exactly what I would like, its complicated a bit by my need for a seekbar to always sit on top.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main1);
setContentView(mLayout);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutFile);
mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main1);
```

Reason: `findViewById` works on the current content view. Before you have set a content view `findViewById` will always return null. You will therefore get a NullPointerException on the last line you posted.